# Using dask distributed with large memory shared in a function call

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am using Dask on a HPC cluster with 4 nodes, and each node has 12 cores.
My code is pure Python dealing with lists and sets, and doing most of the computation in tight Python for loops. I read an answer here which suggests to use more processes and less threads for such computation.

If I have
`client = Client(n_workers=24, threads_per_worker=2)`
will a computation on Python list when using `.map()` and `.compute()` split up the work into 48 chunks in parallel? Wouldn't the GIL allow only one thread, and hence only 24 computations in parallel?
EDIT: How is that if I use multiprocessing module and call a pool of threads, on a single node it is faster? Can I use `dask` with 4 workers (1 worker per node), and 12 pool of threads from the multiprocessing module?

My stripped down code looks like this:

```
b = db.from_sequence([some_list], npartitions=48).map(my_func, g, k)
m_op = b.compute()

def my_func(g, k):
    # several for loops
    return
```

The data `g` is a pretty huge list, and this gets duplicated if I use more number of processes, and hence becomes the bottleneck. I also tried using
`gx = dask.delayed(g)` and passing `gx` to the function. This is also both memory and time consuming.
I understand (from the answers on stackoverflow), that I can use:
`[future] = c.scatter([g])`
but if all my workers randomly use the data `g`, I will have to `broadcast`, and this will again be memory consuming.
Please note that I am not modifying `g` in my function.
What is the right approach to tackle this?

One other minor observation/question about `dask` is:
`my_func` is searching for something, and returns a list of found elements. If a particular worker did not find an element, the return is an empty list. In the end to concatenate the output, I have an ugly piece of code like below:

```
for sl in m_op:                                                                                                                                                               
    for item in sl:                                                                                                                                                                    
        if item != []:                                                                                                                                                                 
            nm_op.append(item)
```

Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks a lot for your time.